# How to track LAN usage? (AKA 'top for LAN')

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, monitoring

There's an evil application that is eating ALL my upload bandwidth (I'm brazilian, it's only ~35kbps) for like 80% of the time my PC is turned on.

I would like to know if there's any way to track this usage and discover what app is doing this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about [nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/)? In my opinion, it is lot more humane. Lists which command/program using network and how much bandwidth for each of them, in realtime.

Install it in ubuntu/debian systems with:

> sudo apt-get install nethogs

Run it to monitor your network interface like this:

> sudo nethogs eth0

[image]

Comment: very interesting! =D Fix my problem better than the combo iftop+netstat. Not that both are not good, they are awesome, but not for what I needed. =D

Comment: this doesn't seem to have a batch mode.

Answer (score 19):

`iftop` is a console/shell-based program similar to top that can use the pcap library (also used by tcpdump and wireshark). It is available for Ubuntu from Universe.

```
sudo aptitude install iftop
sudo iftop
```

While running an upgrade on an ubuntu system:

[image]

With netstat, you can find out what process is connected to a particular port or IP. For ports, its a good idea to prefix with a colon.

```
sudo netstat -plantu | grep "some_port_number_or_ip_address"
```

For example, to look at open connections for ssh:

```
sudo netstat -plantu | grep :22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2376/sshd       
tcp        0      0 10.13.37.122:22         10.13.37.105:59130      ESTABLISHED 4033/sshd: jtimberm
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2376/sshd
```

You can also look for open port connections with lsof:

```
sudo lsof -i:22
COMMAND  PID       USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    2376       root    3u  IPv4   5613      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    2376       root    4u  IPv6   5615      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    4033       root    3u  IPv4  11608      0t0  TCP 10.13.37.122:ssh->10.13.37.105:59130 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    4086 jtimberman    3u  IPv4  11608      0t0  TCP 10.13.37.122:ssh->10.13.37.105:59130 (ESTABLISHED)
```

You can get more information about the open files from lsof with -p PID.

```
sudo lsof -p 2376
```

(Lots of output from that suppressed)

Comment: With this program I could determine where IT was eating my connection... and with netstat I could determine who was doing this. I need to mark those both answers as correct! XD

Comment: I really don't think it's fair to edit your answer and add a lot of new info... but i can't think about any other solution, so.. thank you again =]

Comment: @Igoru Just making the answer better so people get more relevant information if they're searching for questions similar to your own.

Comment: Wait...is that an Ubuntu system? It looks like OS X.

Comment: I ssh'd to an ubuntu system from my mac.

Answer (score 9):

[ntop](http://www.ntop.org/) is your friend.  Packages are in linux repos and macports.

Comment: ntop is an excellent program, but it is probably overkill and overcomplicated for this.

Comment: I don't think it's friendly as I would like to... I think there are so much info for what I need. And your answer is not exactly.... helful. But thank you anyway =]

Answer (score 5):

In addition to using iftop to identify the address and port that's using bandwidth, you can use netstat to identify the process

> sudo netstat -ntp

This will show all TCP connections open and the process name/id attached to each.

Comment: As I can't vote "accepted" for both you and `iftop`, I'll accept him - that showed me EXACTLY when and how someone was eating my bandwidth - and vote you up 'cos with `netstat` I could know who I should kill. Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `lsof -i tcp:80` to concentrate your search on one port. This particular version will list all the processes connected on tcp port 80.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, iftop's user interface is not well-designed. In practice there is hardly ever a need for viewing the IPs or hostnames in realtime. If I needed, a listing of all current connections, I would just go with netstat as jtimberman explained.

For my purposes, bmon is better suited than iftop. It has a very simplistic user interface with support for multiple interfaces and drawing of "graphs". Here is a screenshot:

[image: bmon]

If you do not need all the features bmon offers, [bwm-ng](http://www.gropp.org/?id=projects&sub=bwm-ng) might be the perfect tool for you. It only shows the current occupied bandwidth per interface -- no more and no less:

[image: bwm-ng]

Answer (score 2):

[nload](http://www.debuntu.org/nload-a-network-traffic-analyser/) is a great tool for monitoring bandwidth in real time and easily installed in Ubuntu or Debian with sudo apt-get install nload.

```
Device eth0 [10.10.10.5] (1/2):
=====================================================================================
Incoming:


                               .         ...|    
                               #         ####|   
                           .. |#|  ...   #####.         ..          Curr: 2.07 MBit/s
                          ###.###  #### #######|.     . ##      |   Avg: 1.41 MBit/s
                         ########|#########################.   ###  Min: 1.12 kBit/s
             ........    ###################################  .###  Max: 4.49 MBit/s
           .##########. |###################################|#####  Ttl: 1.94 GByte
Outgoing:
            ##########  ###########    ###########################
            ##########  ###########    ###########################
            ##########. ###########   .###########################
            ########### ###########  #############################
            ########### ###########..#############################
           ############ ##########################################
           ############ ##########################################
           ############ ##########################################  Curr: 63.88 MBit/s
           ############ ##########################################  Avg: 32.04 MBit/s
           ############ ##########################################  Min: 0.00 Bit/s
           ############ ##########################################  Max: 93.23 MBit/s
         ############## ##########################################  Ttl: 2.49 GByte
```

Another excellent tool is [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/), also easily apt-get'able:

```
             191Mb      381Mb                 572Mb       763Mb             954Mb     
└────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────┴──────────────────────
box4.local            => box-2.local                      91.0Mb  27.0Mb  15.1Mb
                      <=                                  1.59Mb   761kb   452kb
box4.local            => box.local                         560b   26.8kb  27.7kb
                      <=                                   880b   31.3kb  32.1kb
box4.local            => userify.com                         0b   11.4kb  8.01kb
                      <=                                  1.17kb  2.39kb  1.75kb
box4.local            => b.resolvers.Level3.net              0b     58b    168b
                      <=                                     0b     83b    288b
box4.local            => stackoverflow.com                   0b     42b     21b
                      <=                                     0b     42b     21b
box4.local            => 224.0.0.251                         0b      0b    179b
                      <=                                     0b      0b      0b
224.0.0.251           => box-2.local                         0b      0b      0b
                      <=                                     0b      0b     36b
224.0.0.251           => box.local                           0b      0b      0b
                      <=                                     0b      0b     35b


─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
TX:           cum:   37.9MB   peak:   91.0Mb     rates:   91.0Mb  27.1Mb  15.2Mb
RX:                  1.19MB           1.89Mb              1.59Mb   795kb   486kb
TOTAL:               39.1MB           92.6Mb              92.6Mb  27.9Mb  15.6Mb
```

Don't forget about the classic and powerful sar and netstat utilities on older *nix!

Answer (score 1):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is also a very good (multiplatform) app for monitoring network traffic. Here's a description from the site:

> Wireshark is the world's foremost
>   network protocol analyzer, and is the
>   de facto (and often de jure) standard
>   across many industries and educational
>   institutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this at the router level depending on your firmware. For example, if you use [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv3/), you could track usage over time and by machine.

Comment: In fact i think that using my ADSL router just to solve this small problem is overkill and overcomplicated. I think it's just an easy thing to solve. But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Install a firewall and, at least temporarily, make it block all outgoing connections.  It should notify you when something tries to make a connection at which point you should have your culprit :-)

here is one of many articles online that gives you info on installing a firewall on ubuntu:
http://linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8256-installing-a-firewall-on-ubuntu

Comment: I think I already have UFW in my Ubuntu.. Anyway I think that this would be a little bit trouble to solve with this approach.. The problem doesn't happen all the time, it, intermitent but a little frequent. But if the other net info apps fails, i'll give the firewall a try! Thank you!