# In linux, how can you tell which processes use the most network bandwidth?

Tags: linux, networking, statistics

In linux, how can you tell which processes use the most network bandwidth? Is there something like "top" for the network?

I know about bwm-ng, but it only shows global statistics, not per-process usage.

Comment: related question here: http://superuser.com/questions/29752/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) does this. All you need to do is run it as root and possibly give it your network interface name as an argument if it doesn't default to the correct one.

Comment: Great tool! Thanks for the hint. It reminds me a bit of iotop (http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) just for network connections. :)